# Kubernetes: Ingress-nginx does not work well with subpaths in the /api route

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to access the subpaths in my backend, but it doesn't seem to work for anything, such as /api/hello, other than /api/.

This is my config:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1

kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    # ADD ANNOTATION
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2

spec:
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api(/|$)(.*)
            # UPDATE PATH
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: server-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000

          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: client-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

When trying to access the subpaths in /api, I will receive 404 not found.

Any help would be very appreciated ~!

Answer (score 0):

Each path in an Ingress is required to have a corresponding path type. Paths that do not include an explicit [pathType](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) will fail validation.

The only supported wildcard character for the path field of an Ingress is the * character. The * character must follow a forward slash (/) and must be the last character in the pattern.
For example, /*, /foo/*, and /foo/bar/* are valid patterns, but *, /foo/bar*, and /foo/*/bar are not.A more specific pattern takes precedence over a less specific pattern. If you have both /foo/* and /foo/bar/*, then /foo/bar/bat is taken to match /foo/bar/*.For more information about path limitations and pattern matching, see the [URL Maps documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map).

**Suggestion : Try by mentioning the path as /api/***

Additional reference doc :

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1120#issuecomment-322007251
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#multiple_backend_services